I18next won't infer namespace prefix
// i18next.d.ts

import 'i18next';
import translations from 'public/locales/ptBR/translation.json';

type key = typeof translations;

declare module 'i18next' {
  interface CustomTypeOptions {
    nsSeparator: '.';
    defaultNS: 'translation';
    resources: {
      translation: key;
    };
  }
}

I've tried lots of things such as using typeof translation, it almost works but keys without nested, which have only a string assigned to it, have a type of keyof string for some odd reason:
resources: key

When I try to use a translation such as:
  {
    path: '/resume',
    label: <Translation>{t => <span>{t('resume')}</span>}</Translation>
  },

it will only work if I passed translation.resume as a param for t() which is wrong
because my initial configuration looks like this:
i18n
  .use(initReactI18next)
  .use(Backend)
  .init({
    backend: {
      loadPath: getTranslateFilePath()
    },
    defaultNS: 'translation',
    lng: 'ptBR',
    fallbackLng: 'ptBR',
    debug: ENV !== 'production',
    interpolation: {
      escapeValue: false
    }
  });

Is there a way to fix this without having to re-write everything else with starting with translation.

So I came up with this solution, (credits to chatgpt), flatten will basically turn your object into a string, like
const object = {
   key1: 'string',
   key2: {
      key3: string;
   }
}

type FlattenObjectKeys = Flatten<typeof Object> // 'key1' | 'key2.key3'


Typing the return of TFunction with the flattened translation object solved the problem.
import translations from 'public/locales/ptBR/translation.json';

  type Flatten<T, P extends string = ''> = {
    [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends Record<string, any> ? Flatten<T[K], `${P}${K}.`> : `${P}${K}`;
  }[keyof T];

  declare type TranslationKeys = Flatten<typeof translations>;

  interface TFunction {
    <K extends TranslationKeys>(key: K, options?: UseTranslationOptions<KPrefix>): string;
  }
}

